# Navbar button hover dont cover

Tags: html, css

[image]My navbar button for signup is not covering the entire line. Can anyone show me how to change this?

my codes are below

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="#home" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#multipledemos" class="nav-links">Multiple Demos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blogdemos" class="nav-links">Blog Demos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#signup" class="nav-links nav-links-btn">SignUp</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

```css
.nav-links-btn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.nav-links-btn:hover {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(198, 137, 255);
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: You may want to add your HTML

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is simply the `<ul>` components and doesn't include its parent container so without that it's impossible to find a viable solution.

However, based on your screenshot I would add the following to your CSS.

```css
.nav-menu li a {
   width: 100%;
}
```

You have to set the width to 100% which tells the child, in this case, the `<ul>` components, to span the full width of the parent.